# What happens if we schedule many jobs in apscheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a flask server running which also has jobs scheduled and run using `apscheduler`. Provided that each of my jobs have their own state, how many jobs can we schedule using `apscheduler`. Does it invoke the job on a separate thread if two jobs tend to run at the same time?

```
scheduler.add_job(report1,cron......)
scheduler.add_job(merge_prs, con.....)
scheduler.add_job(decline_stale_prs, interval.....)
scheduler.add_job(report2, cron.....)
```

In short if I schedule many jobs in a single instance of `apscheduler`, what are the repercussions? In my understanding there would be issues with memory and state. I'd like to hear other perspectives.